# How to handle real API URL via mock server?

Tags: java, junit, mockserver

I have a real API (`https://profiles.production.service/api/person`). And want to mock it using [MockServer](https://www.mock-server.com/).

I'm using JUnit 5 in my integration test:

```
@Rule
val mockServer = MockServerContainer(DockerImageName.parse("jamesdbloom/mockserver:mockserver-5.11.2"))

mockServer.start()
....
MockServerClient("profiles.production.service", mockServer.serverPort)
    .`when`(
        request()
            .withPath("/api/person")
            .withQueryStringParameter("name", "peter")
    )
    .respond(
        response()
            .withBody("Peter the person!")
    )
```

But actually got error:

```
org.mockserver.client.SocketConnectionException: Unable to resolve host profiles.production.service/<unresolved>:55070
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: @Nemanja it won't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. Maybe this would be helpfull for you https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver/issues/108

Answer (score 1):

This answer arrives too late for sure. But I am writing, just in case others come here and have a similar problem.

Looking at the documentation of the [mockserver](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/mockserver/) you can see an example that would make it work. Your code would need to change to:

```
MockServerClient(mockServer.getHost(), mockServer.getServerPort())
```

MockServerContainer is a docker image running on its own. So it will have a different URL than the server you need to mock.

If the problem you have is that you have hardcoded the server name on your class, then you would need to change that class. You will need to inject the server name. In your case

```
"https://%s:%d/api/person".format(mockServer.getHost(), mockServer.getServerPort())
```